# How to fix a hole in laminate floor?

Tags: laminate-floor

I have a hole in a laminated floor as in the picture attached below:
[image]
[image] 
 I have been trying to find some kind of wood sheet or tile of the same color to hide it but could not find any. I cannot take on replacing the board as I have little experience with flooring. So I have been thinking if it is possible to get a piece of the same kind and try to fit it in or perhaps find some kind of tile that I can stick on top of it.

Comment: How good of a repair are you trying to achieve here? The methods for "good as new" may be different from "ugly, but at least my foot doesn't get caught on the hole". Do you still have the missing chunk that was torn from the floor?

Comment: nothing more than fitting in a piece. I was thinking of making this hole rectangular and make it a little deeper so I can fit in a piece of laminated board. But I am not sure where to get a piece from and where I can actually get one. If it is easier to use a filler, I am ok with that but not sure where to get the right filler.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the “Pergo” brand I installed in my place. They used to make filler that matched really well.
You clean the area and trowel the filler in and let it sit until dry. Don’t buy more than needed because the stuff I bought
dried out in an unopened tube after ~2 years. The patch has held up for +8 years and will look better than another brand.
Have you tried their web site to find it?

Comment: can you post a link to the particular filler you mention?

Comment: The link shows what [Home Depot has] (pergo SimpleSolutions   1 oz. Laminate Finishing Putty) it worked well for me. Pergo SimpleSolutions   1 oz. Laminate Finishing Putty can't get the link to work editing on my I phone